# ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR in the network tab when using Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome, iis, google-chrome-devtools, http2, webapi

I've got a website hosted on IIS, http2 enabled, when using Chrome Dev Tools the site fails to load. Every network request comes back with ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR. If I close Dev Tools and refresh the site everything loads as you would expect.

Similarly, if I use edge or firefox, everything works fine even with their respective Dev Tools open. I've confirmed the http2 protocol is being used in each browser.

Disabling HTTP2 in IIS resolves the problem in Chrome.

Does anyone know what Chrome might be doing differently when dev tools is open to get this error? I'm at a loss.

Comment: This error is only related to the client. If you want to get the cause of this error, you can try to compare different browsers requesting data, such as content-length.

Comment: Having the same issue. Were you able to find the answer?

Comment: Having the same issue. Were you able to find the fix?

Comment: Having the same issue. With chrome and edge experience same behavior. Any thoughts ?